# Error: Cannot find module 'node:util' when trying to use "sharp"

Tags: javascript, node.js, sharp

After I installed `sharp` to my Node.js application and tried to use it, the following error shows:

```
/Users/username/Documents/GitHub/Synto-BE/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js:1
Error: Cannot find module 'node:util'
Require stack:
- /Users/username/Documents/GitHub/Synto-BE/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js
- /Users/username/Documents/GitHub/Synto-BE/node_modules/sharp/lib/index.js
- /Users/username/Documents/GitHub/Synto-BE/controller/general/tools.js
- /Users/username/Documents/GitHub/Synto-BE/controller/administration/interview.js
- /Users/username/Documents/GitHub/Synto-BE/services/admin.js
- /Users/username/Documents/GitHub/Synto-BE/routes/index.js
- /Users/username/Documents/GitHub/Synto-BE/index.js
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/username/Documents/GitHub/Synto-BE/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js:6:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/username/Documents/GitHub/Synto-BE/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js',
    '/Users/username/Documents/GitHub/Synto-BE/node_modules/sharp/lib/index.js',
    '/Users/username/Documents/GitHub/Synto-BE/controller/general/tools.js',
    '/Users/username/Documents/GitHub/Synto-BE/controller/administration/interview.js',
    '/Users/username/Documents/GitHub/Synto-BE/services/admin.js',
    '/Users/username/Documents/GitHub/Synto-BE/routes/index.js',
    '/Users/username/Documents/GitHub/Synto-BE/index.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v18.17.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Disabling the part of code using `sharp` doesn't work, only uninstalling it works for me.

May someone tell me how to install it correctly?

Comment: Have you tried `npm install util` per https://www.npmjs.com/package/util ?

Comment: @Sflagg Running that shows `up to date, audited 666 packages in 1s`. I guess that is installed but not found somehow.

Comment: I'd suggest reinstalling node and while you are at it installing the latest version. And in your project npm install sharp for the latest version of sharp.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to add "sharp" to the resolutions of your package.json file:

```
"resolutions": {
    "sharp": "^0.29.0"
  }
```

and the example of package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-sharp-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "sharp": "^0.29.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "sharp": "^0.29.0"
  }
}
```